# Cannot work on action functions using pyspark. Error:

Tags: pyspark

```
This is our code: 
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="m")
    f = sc.textFile('/home/hduser/Downloads/ml-1m/b.csv')   
    genres = ["Action","Adventure","Animation", "Children's","Comedy","Crime Documentary","Drama"," Fantasy","Film-     Noir","Horror","Musical","Mystery","Romance","Sci-Fi","Thriller","War","Western"]
    g = f.map(lambda x:x.split(','))
    r = {} 
    for genre in genres: 
            a = g.filter(lambda x: genre in x[1])
            for i in range(6041):
                u = a.filter(lambda x: int(x[2]) == i)
                x = u.map(lambda x:int(x[3])).sum()
            if u.count() == 0:
                    r[i] = 0
            else:
                    r[i] = float(x)/u.count()
            print(x)

    sc.stop()
```

It shows error while calling sum() function:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 15.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 15.0 (TID 53, 10.70.3.170, executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2127)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2247)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2165)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2241)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2165)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:420)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2132)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2241)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2165)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2241)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2165)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:420)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2132)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2241)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2165)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2241)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2165)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:420)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1925)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1938)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1965)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2127)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2247)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2165)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2241)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2165)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:420)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2132)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2241)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2165)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2241)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2165)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:420)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2132)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2241)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2165)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2241)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2165)
        at 17/07/10 11:51:01 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 49, 10.70.3.232, executor 0): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2023)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:420)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you tell, What is that you are trying to process?

Comment: It is a MovieLens dataset where I am trying to find average rating given by a user of a specific genre. I am able to run on standalone mode but it is giving this error while executing on cluster. Programs given in examples folder of Spark are working fine on cluster.